# admin area getting error 'require is not a function at editor.js:6' after upgrading magento 2 from 2.1.1 to 2.1.17

Tags: magento-2.1, admin, javascript, magento-upgrade

**After upgrading Magento from version 2.1.1 to 2.1.17, I am facing thi**s error

> Uncaught TypeError: require is not a function at editor.js:6

across admin area especially in edit pages

**when I look at html -> head I see that js file**

`en_US/Magento_Backend/js/bootstrap/editor.js`

**is called first before  requirejs file**

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete the existing require js from pub/static/_requirejs/frontend/Namespace/Theme/en_US requirejs-config.js path and refresh the page again so it will regenerate it and solve the error of js not found.

OR

Follow below steps . I think it's solve your problem

1. Remove Your Cache
2. Clean theme by command : grunt clean
3. Run CMD command prompt with administrator privilege
4. run command : grunt exec:yourthemename
5. run command : grunt less:yourthemename
6. run command : grunt watch

Basically working and the right solution, but with the limitations of [#6367](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/6367)